# Rotate 4x4 image patch by multiples of 15 degrees

Tags: python, image, scipy, rotation

I want to find an efficient way to rotate a 4x4 image patches from a larger image by angles that are multiples of 15. I am currently extracting a 6x6 patch e.g. `patch=img[x-3:x+3,y-3:y+3]` and then running `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate(patch,-15*o,reshape=False)[1:5,1:5]`. However, I essentially need to do this at ever location `(x,y)` in the image. I have a "stacked" version of the image with an array of size `(m,n,6,6)` where `m` and `n` are the dimensions of the original image. Even if run `interpolation.rotate` on the stacked version, it looks like it internally simply does it iteratively and it takes a long time.

Since I only need to do this at fixed angles, I am trying to pre-compute some constants and vectorize the implementation so that I can process them all at once. I have tried digging into the implementation of SciPy rotate but it did not help much.

Is there a sensible way to do this?

Comment: When you say "4x4 image patches" do you mean 4 pixels by 4 pixels (16 pixels total)?